# Flutter GoRouter Dynamically Change PageTransition Type with NavigatorObserver

Tags: flutter, navigator, observers, flutter-go-router

I would like to dynamically change the transition used to navigate between pages.

To do so I created an enum that gives two different transition names `TransitionType.fade` and `TransitionType.slide` for example.

I then created an StatefulWidget surrounding the navigator. This stateful widget is updated to reflect the transition of the top most route (`isCurrent`) and all pages then follow that transition. That state can be updated at any time.

However this seems unnecessarily convoluted and I wondered if this could be done instead with a `NavigatorObserver`. All the Observer has to do is contain the state of which transition is to be used and allow that state to be set at any time. Is this possible?

Comment: I think using an InheritedWidget would be more appropriate in this case, if you're interested I can share an example.

Comment: @GuillaumeRoux That's ok. I thought there might be something more out of the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an `InheritedWidget` would be the way to go instead of a `NavigatorObserver`.

Here's a code sample that implement a `GoRouterTransition` widget which you can access using `GoRouterTransition.of(context)` or `GoRouterTransition.maybeOf(context)` to read and set your `TransitionType` (you'll have to wrap this widget on top of your `MaterialApp`):

```dart
class GoRouterTransition extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoRouterTransition({
    super.key,
    required this.child,
  });

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<GoRouterTransition> createState() => GoRouterTransitionState();

  static GoRouterTransitionState? maybeOf(BuildContext context) {
    return context
        .dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_TransitionTypeScope>()
        ?.data;
  }

  static GoRouterTransitionState of(BuildContext context) {
    final state = maybeOf(context);
    assert(state != null, 'No GoRouterTransition found in context');
    return state!;
  }
}

class GoRouterTransitionState extends State<GoRouterTransition> {
  TransitionType _type = TransitionType.fade;
  TransitionType get type => _type;
  set type(TransitionType value) => setState(() => _type = value);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _TransitionTypeScope(
      data: this,
      child: widget.child,
    );
  }
}

class _TransitionTypeScope extends InheritedWidget {
  const _TransitionTypeScope({
    required this.data,
    required super.child,
  });

  final GoRouterTransitionState data;

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(_TransitionTypeScope oldWidget) {
    return data.type != oldWidget.data.type;
  }
}
```

You then just have to create your own custom `GoRoute` object which will build your page with the correct transition:

```dart
class DynamicGoRoute extends GoRoute {
  DynamicGoRoute({
    required super.path,
    required GoRouterWidgetBuilder builder,
    super.routes = const <RouteBase>[],
  }) : super(
          pageBuilder: (context, state) {
            final type = GoRouterTransition.of(context).type;

            switch (type) {
              case TransitionType.fade:
                return FadePage<void>(
                  builder: (context) => builder(context, state),
                );
              case TransitionType.slide:
                return SlidePage<void>(
                  builder: (context) => builder(context, state),
                );
            }
          },
        );
}
```

[You can try the complete sample on zapp.run](https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-zq4806omq490?entry=lib%2Fmain.dart)

Comment: Ooo I like that. That's much nicer than the inherited widget I made to control this.